# Using relaxed dictionary to map values in column

Tags: python, string, pandas, dictionary, series

I was wondering if someone could help me match a column of strings with a sort of relaxed dictionary in python. So I have the following python data frame:

```
String                      Colour
8392apple8309
8dbsfhorange9anld
38banananflks9
```

and this dictionary:

```
_dict
{'apple':'Red',
'orange':'Orange'
'banana':'Yellow'}
```

I have written this function:

```
def fruitsearch(string):
    return [value for key, value in _dict.items() if string in key.lower()]
```

which is able to take substrings of my keys, such as fruitsearch('app') and return the correct colour, red. What I would like to do, however, is for the function to find keys in my dataframe column "String" and return the correct colour to the second column in the dataframe, colour, so it will look like this:

```
String                        Colour
8392apple8309                 Red
8dbsfhorange9anld             Orange
38banananflks9                Yellow
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one approach.

**Demo:**

```
import pandas as pd


def fruitsearch(string):
    _dict = {'apple':'Red', 'orange':'Orange', 'banana':'Yellow'}
    for key, value in _dict.items():
        if key.lower() in string:
            return value 
    return None


df = pd.DataFrame({"String": ["8392apple8309", "8dbsfhorange9anld", "38banananflks9"]})
df["Colour"] = df["String"].apply(fruitsearch)

print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
              String  Colour
0      8392apple8309     Red
1  8dbsfhorange9anld  Orange
2     38banananflks9  Yellow
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently you are iterating your dictionary within a *row-wise* calculation. For efficiency, especially with a large number of rows, consider *column-wise* operations for each dictionary item. In this case, you can use [`pd.Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) and supply the argument `regex=False` to improve performance.

```
for k, v in _dict.items():
    df.loc[df['String'].str.contains(k, regex=False), 'Colour'] = v

print(df)

              String  Colour
0      8392apple8309     Red
1  8dbsfhorange9anld  Orange
2     38banananflks9  Yellow
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, that's really helpful!